# Unable to login after keyboard configuration

Tags: keyboard, login, configuration

I use Ubuntu 21.04. After a `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` command, my AltGr and Alt buttons no longer work. The point is my password need an @, so I can't login again to open a terminal and reverse my bliss. I tried various combinations to make it appear in vain.

For instance, when I tape on AltGr, a symbol that I had never seen before appears. If I tape again it disappears and so on ... I try also : Ctrl + Alt + 0 = nothing happens, Alt + 64 = 64...

I have choosen an AZERTY keyboard : français(azerty) and everything else on the keyboard works fine.

I try to enter in recovery mode in order to start a root session but the root password need also an @ ...

Does anyone have a solution that would allow me to access my session or a terminal again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using an on screen keyboard? You can set that all up with the mouse so shouldn’t be an issue that some  keyboard options aren’t there - and hopefully that will allow you to reverse the problem:
Open settings and open the universal access option. There’s a toggle for the on screen keyboard.

Comment: So obvious ... Thank you a lot

Comment: Excellent - very pleased I could help!